# Graficar dataframe con grafica pastel

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Debo filtrar unos datos de un dataframe y graficar con una grafica de pastel, lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente.

**PONGO UN ENLACE DONDE ESTA UN CSV CON LOS DATOS QUE CONVERTI EN DATAFRAME PARA QUIEN LO NECESITE**
[link del csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O3LmXBidBq9GDmDS-SMkBBOhJTuvZqs_/view?usp=sharing)

```
exgrupo = df['ExGrupo']
exGru = df['ExGrupo'].value_counts()

plt.pie(exGru, labels=exgrupo)
plt.show()
```

Me debe aparecer algo asi, como el ejemplo que me dan.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de realizarlo, no se si filtro mal o que estoy haciendo mal, porque me aparece este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que estoy haciendo mal, me gustaría saber si es la grafica o al filtrar. Soy nuevo en el tema de DATAFRAME, muchas gracias

Comment: imposible de determinar sin saber de donde provienen los datos. Por favor agrega tu DataFrame

Comment: Vale, agregare una imagen donde muestro el dataframe y sus columnas

Comment: Nop, imagen no. Debes agregarlo como texto, sino como quieres que hagamos las pruebas?

Comment: Es un csv con muchos datos, mirare como pongo una prueba o el archivo en si

Comment: puedes poner unos cuantos datos o un enlace del archivo subido a la nube

Comment: Ahi ya puse el link, gracias por guiarme y sugerirme

Comment: ya me di cuenta del error, ahora escribo una respuesta :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé como no vi el error, pero se debe a que la cantidad de labels no concuerda con el número de datos graficados esto se debe a que al usar `value_counts()` se cuenta la cantidad de datos. Lo que debes hacer es:

```py
#.. resto de codigo
plt.pie(exGru, labels=exGru.keys())
plt.show()
```

como vez estamos extrayendo las llaves de la variable `exGru` que contiene los datos contabilizados y guardados. Si tienes algún problema con esto puedes usar `exGru.to_dict().keys()`.

Con esto tu gráfica ya se verá pero se verá de forma muuuyy rara/desordenada/confusa por lo que agregué algunos parámetros y otros métodos.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6)) #definimos el tamaño del cuadro
labels=exGru.keys() #obtenemos los labels

plt.pie(exGru, autopct='%1.1f%%') #graficamos
plt.legend(labels, bbox_to_anchor =(1, 1)) #especificamos la leyenda
plt.show()
```

Con esto tu gráfica se verá más bonita :D.

Comment: Muchas gracias entendí muy claramente lo que estaba haciendo mal, tengo que realizar otros filtro, si presento algún otro problema vuelvo y pregunteo. Muchas gracias ♥